# Is it possible to port Apple .frameworks files to Linux?

Tags: swift, linux, xcode, macos, header-files

I am trying to build a swift project on Linux which depends on `CoreBluetooth.framework`. It builds fine on OSX, but on Linux it gives me the following error

```
~/ReWork/.../DeviceManager.swift:10:8: error no such module 'CoreBluetooth'
import CoreBluetooth
       ^
```

I used Xcode to hunt around, and found the actual .framework file on my mac, which looks to contain a bunch of headers. Is it at all possible to put this on my linux box and point swift to it?

Comment: No. CoreBluetooth most probably has a bunch of dependencies on other Apple frameworks, some of which is probably written in Objective-C.

Comment: Is this true for .framwork files in general?

Comment: The Apple ones? Yes. Most frameworks haven't been rewritten in Swift.

Comment: What language they're written in is a bit of a red herring. They're components of the operating system, and will not work outside that environment. Even if you had the source code, it wouldn't work, because it depends on lower-level components of macOS as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. CoreBluetooth is a component of macOS, and is not available on Linux.